# How to hide the shadow in the header React Navigation v.6.x?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Here's what I've tried to remove the header shadow,

```js
<Stack.Screen
  name="Home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  options={{ 
    headerTitle: props => <MainHeader {...props} /> , 
    headerBackTitle: '',
    headerTintColor: '#0f0f2b',
    headerHideShadow: true
  }}
/>

function MainHeader(){
    return (
        <View style={{height: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0}}></View>
    );
}
```

But that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Set **headerShadowVisible** to **false** in the options, like this

```
<Stack.Screen 
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{ headerShadowVisible: false }}
/>
```

Comment: I Wonder, if it works? then why you not mark this answer as accepted? @NikSilver

Answer (score 0):

Use property `headerShadowVisible`

See my [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/header-without-shadow-rn-navigation-6x)